# What language to write USB 3.0 application for ADC demo board?

Tags: usb, programming

I need some suggestion/guidance on which language/setup to use to create an application with USB 3.0 connectivity that processes 1.6Gbps of data in real-time.

The application collects data from an ADC and plots it on a chart in the application. Basically, it is a high-speed data acquisition board I am designing, and need software to pair with the board.

Target operating system is Windows, but eventually support for OS X and Linux will be needed.

I have experience using FTDI USB 2.0 serial-mode chips, but not sure if USB 3.0 will be the same for speeds at 1.6Gbps.

Any comments/suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirements are similar to PC-based software-defined radios. High-end existing systems might be a place to start looking for design ideas.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for pointing me in the write direction! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The speed critical parts that handle real-time number crunching should be written in a compiled and efficient language, like C or C++.  1.6Gbps is 200MB/s, so depending on the amount of processing you're doing...let's just say you shouldn't write this in ruby or python.

Now, if your processing is pipeline-able (doesn't require branching or moving up and down the program stack), or basically just a series of operations that are fixed and do not depend on the contents of the data, the same things will be done to all the data, then this is what things like OpenCL or CUDA were made for.  This lets you perform these operations on the computer's GPU, using it almost like DSP.  OpenCL works on all graphics cards, CUDA is Nvidia specific, so I would recommend OpenCL.  It also can fall back and use the CPU.

OpenCL is a framework rather than a language, but it does specify C99 as the preferred language to use with it.

Also, Kevin Reid's comment is a great tip - SDRs do exactly this - process a flood of data coming from somewhere (usually USB 2.0 or 3.0) and an excellent place to start.  A simple one might be to look at how the rtl-sdr driver does it. The code is available [here](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr).

Comment: The processing needed is taking the FFT of the incoming bit stream, which are time samples of ADC output data at a fixed sampling rate (20-bits per sample at 40 MSPS). I want the application to continuously update the FFT plot on the screen that the user sees, at a rate of about 10 times a second (so it appears to be in real-time). Each FFT is 32K samples. If OpenCL can take FFTs, that would be awesome. Will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Robin Tsang if all you want is FFT @ 40Msps you might consider FPGA. A decent chip, clocked at 200MHz, gives you 5 clocks/sample and the result may even fit down a USB 2.0 channel.